# Serialize кавычек

Tags: php

Как за-seralize-ить текст с кавычками? Точнее serialize нормально работает, а unserialize не выполняется со всеми видами кавычек, даже книжными. Результат пустой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извините, а какой смысл делать serialize для строки ?
serialize это сериализация объекта или массива в строку. Зачем из строки делать строку - не понятно.

Или вы путаете термины, либо мы не понимаем друг-друга.

Если вы пытаетесь всётаки сериализовать массив с текстом у которого есть кавычки: то проблем быть не должно:

```
php -r '$a=array("a" => "ab\"c"); $z = serialize($a); echo $z."\n"; print_r(unserialize($z));'

a:1:{s:1:"a";s:4:"ab"c";}
Array
(
    [a] => ab"c
)
```

*UPD*

Что бы исправить вашу проблему нужно:

либо **установить magic_quotes_gpc в Off в php.ini** (после изменений в php.ini нужно перезапускать апач) либо пробегатся по массиву и **для каждого элемента делать stripslashes**

я бы предпочел первый вариант.

Comment: Имеется ввиду массив с текстами... надо засериалайзить и сохранить в базу.

Comment: тоже не понял....

Comment: Есть форма, там 3 текстовых поля. В эти поля вбивается текст. на сервер получаю массив этих со значениями этих полей. После сериализирую и записываю в базу. 

Проблема происходит, потому что я через форму отправляю текс. а так проблем нет.

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: в любом случае зло получается :DDD

Comment: @AlexWindHope, Ну почему же ?

ЗЫ: Я более чем уверен что на вашей инсталяции php этот флаг выключен :)

Comment: Ой, прошу прощения, прочиталось что 
**установить magic_quotes_gpc в On** :D

magic_quotes_gpc надо рубить нафиг, хотя бы даже потому что эта директива объявлена нежелательной

Comment: stripslashes - помог. Благодарствую. Настройки PHP не могу изменить...

Answer (score 2):

Добавление к ответу [@shurik](/users/1182/shurik)

Если это хостинг без возможности редактировать php.ini:

```
function stripslashes_rec(&$link) {
  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc() && !get_magic_qoutes_runtime()) return true;
  if (is_array($link)) {
    foreach ($link as &$element)
      stripslashes_rec($element);
    } else $link = stripslashes($link);
  return true;
  }
// и в начале скрипта
stripslashes_rec($_GET);
stripslashes_rec($_POST);
stripslashes_rec($_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот этим символом -

> \
>
> ```
> Вот так:
> <?php
> $a = "system \"Windows\"";
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Это ничего не меняет:

    s:4:"prim";s:12:"\"\'dfdf";

такая же ерунда происходит

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = array('text' => '"text"');
echo serialize($ar);
print_r(unserialize(serialize($ar)));
print_r(unserialize('a:1:{s:4:"text";s:6:""text"";}'));
//a:1:{s:4:"text";s:6:""text"";}Array ( [text] => "text" ) Array ( [text] => "text" )
```

Двойные кавычки функцию не пугают. Но все равно лучше используйте json.

Comment: А почему-то я как добавлю кавычки, так все перестает работать. Текст отправляется через форму с сайта AJAX-ом.

От версии PHP зависит? у меня 5.2 стоит.

Кстати, у меня почему кавычку считает за два символа.

Comment: Хм... Если это просто текст, без претензий на исполнение, заменяйте кавычки их html-аналогами: &quot; , &#039; .

>меня почему кавычку считает за два символа

Двойную как две одинарных? =)

Comment: html-аналагии не катят, потому что текст в последствии будет включен в PDF документ.

    Двойную как две одинарных? =)

нет...и одинарную тоже за два символа считает.

    s:4:"prim";s:6:"ээ''";

Если вручную исправить и написать вместо 6-ки 4-ку, то нормально работает.

addslashes уже пробовал - не помогло.